# 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'caption' in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have written this simple image upload app, where users should be able to add caption to the uploaded image.

the views is:

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    thisuser =User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)

    args= {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        picform = PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if picform.is_valid():
            newpic = UserPic(picfile = request.FILES['picfile'])
            newpic = picform.save(commit=False)
            newpic.user_id = request.user.id
            newpic.caption = request.POST.caption # <--problematic line
            newpic.save()
            message = "file %s is uploaded" % newpic

            args['pic'] = newpic.picfile
            args['caption'] = newpic.caption

    else:
        picform = PicForm()  

    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['picform'] = picform    

    return render_to_response('pics/upload.html',args,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The model is:

```
class UserPic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    picfile = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to= get_uplaod_file_name,sizes=((200,200),))
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=200 , blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the template:

```
<div>   
Upload New picture

        <form action="/pics/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

        <ul  class="list-unstyled  form-group">
    {{picform.as_ul}}
        </ul>
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
 </div>
```

When I upload photo, fill the caption field and submit the form,, I get:

```
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'caption'
```

I tried different things instead of `newpic.caption = request.POST.caption` but none worked. So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
request.POST['caption']
```

or

```
request.POST.get('caption', 'Default').
```

Both get the caption value from the form post data. The latter is just a safer way in my opinion by specifying a default value for caption.

Comment: It worked. Many thanks! Any reason the second form is safer though?

Comment: It's a personal preference of how you use it, I prefer to use the second method. The second method just sets the value of caption to 'Default' if for some or other reason it's not in the post data. You specify a default value instead of the application trying to access a key which is not there and raising an exception.

Comment: Similar issue, the version `request.POST['caption']` worked for me.
`